# Tensorflow: optimizer.minimize() - "ValueError: Shape must be rank 0 but is rank 1

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to adapt a Tensorflow r0.12 code (from https://github.com/ZZUTK/Face-Aging-CAAE) to version 1.2.1 and I am having issues with optimizer.minimize().

In this case I am using GradientDescent, but the following error message is only slightly different (in terms of shapes provided) when I try with different optimizers:

```
ValueError: Shape must be rank 0 but is rank 1 for 'GradientDescent/update_E_con
v0/w/ApplyGradientDescent' (op: 'ApplyGradientDescent') 
with input shapes: [5,5,1,64], [1], [5,5,1,64].
```

Where [5,5] is my kernels size, 1 is the number of initial channels and 64 is the number of filters in the first convolution. This is the convolutional encoder network it is referring to:

```
E_conv0:    (100, 128, 128, 64)
E_conv1:    (100, 64, 64, 128)
E_conv2:    (100, 32, 32, 256)
E_conv3:    (100, 16, 16, 512)
E_conv4:    (100, 8, 8, 1024)
E_conv5:    (100, 4, 4, 2048)
...
```

This is code that's triggering the error:

```
self.EG_optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(
    learning_rate=EG_learning_rate, 
    beta1=beta1
).minimize(
    loss=self.loss_EG,
    global_step=self.EG_global_step,
    var_list=self.E_variables + self.G_variables
)
```

Where:

```
EG_learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(
    learning_rate=learning_rate,
    global_step=self.EG_global_step,
    decay_steps=size_data / self.size_batch * 2,
    decay_rate=decay_rate,
    staircase=True
)

self.EG_global_step = tf.get_variable(name='global_step',shape=1, initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0), trainable=False)
```

And

```
self.E_variables = [var for var in trainable_variables if 'E_' in var.name]
self.G_variables = [var for var in trainable_variables if 'G_' in var.name]

self.loss_EG = tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(self.input_image - self.G))
```

After some debugging I now believe the problem comes from the minimize() method. The error seems to be attributed to the last parameter (var_list) but when I try to comment out the second or third parameter, the error remains the same and is just attributed to the first parameter (loss).

I have changed the code with respect to the one currently on GitHub to adapt it to the new version, so I worked a lot on tf.variable_scope(tf.get_variable_scope(), reuse=True). Could this be the cause?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: have you tried https://www.tensorflow.org/install/migration to upgrade your code ?

Answer (score 0):

It's tricky to decode, since it comes from an internal op, but this error message points to the cause:

> ValueError: Shape must be rank 0 but is rank 1 for 'GradientDescent/update_E_conv0/w/ApplyGradientDescent' (op: 'ApplyGradientDescent') 
>   with input shapes: [5,5,1,64], [1](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/15b953a5d8254a89bcd7e0f3dc9843c101846cb2/tensorflow/core/ops/training_ops.cc#L70), [5,5,1,64].

One of the inputs to the `ApplyGradientDescent` op is a rank 1 tensor (i.e. a vector) when it should be a rank 0 tensor (i.e. a scalar). Looking at the [definition of the `ApplyGradientDescent` op](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/15b953a5d8254a89bcd7e0f3dc9843c101846cb2/tensorflow/core/ops/training_ops.cc#L70), the only scalar input is `alpha`, or the learning rate.

Therefore, it appears that the `EG_learning_rate` tensor is a vector when it should be a scalar. A simple fix would be to "slice" a scalar from the `EG_learning_rate` tensor when you construct the `tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer`:

```
scalar_learning_rate = EG_learning_rate[0]

self.EG_optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(
    learning_rate=scalar_learning_rate, 
    beta1=beta1
).minimize(
    loss=self.loss_EG,
    global_step=self.EG_global_step,
    var_list=self.E_variables + self.G_variables
)
```